# What makes the '’The Algebra of Data' a better choice for data processing?

Tags: algebraixlib

I have read the book ’The Algebra of Data: A Foundation for the Data Economy’ and white paper ‘Data Algebra Hiding in Plain Sight’.
I would like to know people comments on ‘The Algebra of Data’ on following questions
What makes the ‘The Algebra of Data’ a good choice for defining data object and data processing?
What are the key benefits of using ‘The Algebra of Data’’ over other data storing and processing applications specifically SQL databases?
What are the general benefits of using ‘The Algebra of Data’?

Comment: Too broad and Primarily opinion based.....

Comment: @KevinDTimm. Please confirm that you have knowledge of 'The Algebra of Data' before declaring contents too broad. Thanks

Comment: You have asked an open ended question whose answer could be book length.  Please see the [help] section to understand the purpose of SO.

Answer (score 2):

(I am one of the authors of the book.) In response to: What makes "Algebra of Data" a good choice for defining data objects and data processing:

Pragmatically, right now, there are a relatively small number of developers employing data algebra. If I understand the situation at Algebraix Data Corp  correctly, they are using it to build a SQL accelerator for the Spark environment. Aside from that activity a set of Python libraries (see http://algebraixdata.github.io/algebraixlib/) have been created for programmers to experiment with using the algebra programmatically. So right now there is not much in the way of software tools for implementing data algebra.

Realistically, the existence of data algebra has only just been made public and thus it is early days. It is not possible for me to know how fast it will get adopted, but it is out there and anyone who wishes to build software that employs it can do so.

The key benefits of using Data Algebra are simply the benefits of mathematics applied to any area. Many of the problems that data algebra could help with have been reasonably well dealt with by programmers, often quite a while ago. You might be able to improve on what's been done with, say a PC database, but there's probably little to be gained. (I cannot know that for sure, but it seems probable).

However Mathematics scales almost indefinitely - and does so accurately. Consequently the  bigger the problem (data volumes, data speed, data variability and so on) the more useful it proves to be. So this is where it will make its initial impact, I expect.

At some point there will be a need to define an algebraic query language (probably a specialization of and extension of SQL) but right now I don't think anyone is working on that. If you consider the relational model of data - which was a failed attempt at a data algebra, it took quite a while for SQL to develop from it and for the model to come into general use.

I hope this helps

Comment: Sounds interesting, but there is a long track record of ideas from disciplines like universal algebra, category theory and topology being promoted as grand unifying tools in computer science but never quite leading anywhere. When I was in grad school I studied for a while something called "Formal Concept Analysis" that was supposed to revolutionize AI -- but it is still mostly an academic backwater 25 years later. On the other hand, certain ideas from category theory really caught on in Haskell, so you never can tell ahead of time where things will go. Good luck.